# DDD rich domain model, and aggregate root

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am trying to develop a small application that allows a user to create tenants for a multi-tenant application.
On the production server, we have 2 instances of the site, a version N (production) and a version N + 1 (test production).

Some tenants are test-tenants. So we must can change a tenant of site version.

When a tenant is assigned to a site, I need to configure IIS using the API Microsoft.Web.Administration to add bindings to the site instance.

Example: if we pass the tenant (tenant1) from production to test production, we must remove the binding "www.tenant1.com" of the site "production" and add it to the site "production-test"

For this domain, I designed two aggregates roots

```cs
public class Tenant : IEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DbInstanceName { get; set; }
    public Site Site { get; set; }
    public virtual Icollection<Binding> Bindings { get; set; }
}

public class Binding: IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public string Protocol { get; set; }
    public string Adress { get; set; }
}
```

When I load a tenant, it's bindings are loaded, site is loading but not site's bindings..

```cs
public class Site : IEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IISiteName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Binding> Bindings { get; set; }
}
```

When I load a site, it's bindings are loaded, tenant is loading but not tenant's bindings..

First, it is acceptable to have a tenant list in the site, and site in a tenant, knowing that tenant and site are aggregates?

Then I have a use case that poses problem to me, since the view which will allow users to edit the tenant, contains a combo with sites, the association to a website can be changed when tenant is updated.

first approach :

```cs
public class TenantService {
    public void UpdateTenant(Tenant tenant, int newSiteId) {

    var currentTenant = _repoTenant.find(tenant.Id);
    var newSite = _repoSite.find(newSiteId);

    // mapping
    // ...

    if(tenant.Site != null) {
        // important: i have to load site from it's aggregate, because I KNOW (but if i was another developer i wouldn't)
        // that's site's bindings are note loaded from client's aggregate
        var currentSite = _repoSite.find(tenant.Site);
        currentSite.RemoveTenant(tenant);
        // iisadministrator, supply an abstraction to configure binding on iis
        iisadministrator.SetBinding(currentSite .IISSiteName, currentSite.Bindings);
    }

    newSite.Add(tenant);
    // iisadministrator, supply an abstraction to configure binding on iis
    iisadministrator.SetBinding(newSite.IISSiteName, newSite.Bindings);

    // saving..
}
}

public class Site : IEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public void AddTenant(Tenant tenant) {
        this.Tenants.Add(tenant);
        tenants.Bindings.ToList().Foreach( b => this.Bindings.Add(b));
    }

    public void RemoveTenant(Tenant tenant) {
        this.Tenants.Remove(tenant);
        tenants.Bindings.ToList().Foreach( b => this.Bindings.Remove(b));
    }               
}
```

3 problems for this approach:

- When another developer add a tenant to a site, i connot be sure he has removed from its former site before
- When a developer adds a tenant into a site, i cannot be sure he updates bindings on IIS
- May be a problem of modeling: the developer must know that it has to fully load the current site (to have all its bindings and can update iis)
  Second one:

```cs
public class TenantService {
    public void UpdateTenant(Tenant tenant, int newSiteId) {

        var currentTenant = _repoTenant.find(tenant.Id);
        var newSite = _repoSite.find(newSiteId);

        // mapping
        // ...

        // iisadministrator, supply an abstraction to configure binding on iis
        newSite.Add(client, iisAdministrator);

        // saving.. 
    }
}

public class Site : IEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public void AddTenant(Tenant tenant, IISAdministrator iisadministrator) {

        if(tenant.Site == Site) return; 


        if(tenant.Site != null) tenant.Site.removeTenant(tenant); <--  all bindings are not loaded (1)

        this.Tenants.Add(tenant);
        tenants.Bindings.ToList().Foreach( b => this.Bindings.Add(b));
        iisadministrator.SetBinding(this.IISSiteName, this.Bindings);
    }

    public void RemoveTenant(Tenant tenant, IISAdministrator iisadministrator) {
        this.Tenants.Remove(tenant);
        tenants.Bindings.ToList().Foreach( b => this.Bindings.Remove(b));
        iisadministrator.SetBinding(this.IISSiteName, this.Bindings); <-- all bindings are not loadedn see(1)
    }               
}
```

Better but other problems here:

- all current Site's bindings are not loaded, so there is a problem when updating iis

Also in 2 cases, how to make change of entities and changes of IIS in the same transaction?

About modeling, how to choose between:

```cs
tenant.setSite(Site site) { }
tenant.changeSite(Site oldSite, Site newSite) { }
site.AddTenant(Tenant tenant) { }
```

is there a methodology for that?

Thank's.

Comment: I really do not get why there is an inter-communication between production and production-test. I mean, shouldn't these environments be completely isolated? It's the first time that I see an attempt to build such environment.

Comment: Thank's.

In fact I quite agree with you... i was not agree with this choice at the beginning.

We are a very small company (2 developers), we develop a SaaS solution for our (12) customers.
Sometimes a customer needs a new feature, and we have to be reactive to integrate these new business rules into the application.

We rarely have time to integrate unit tests. That's why we have a production version test. When the new feature is
develop, we migrates the customer who asked, and he become the application tester.....

Comment: Why do all tenants have their own domain? Are you in the site hosting business? I do not think that tenancy has to be segregated by domain, no? It makes it much more complicated to manage tenancy. For 12 users you could just go and create all accounts in the dev upfront and let them active indefinitely. Also, aggregates shouldn't directly reference other aggregates since aggregates are transactional boundaries and transactional boundaries shouldn't be nested in most scenarios. Use identity reference between aggregates.

Answer (score 2):

> First, it is acceptable to have a tenant list in the site, and site in a tenant, knowing that tenant and site are aggregates?

No, that doesn't make any sense.  A list of references might make sense, depending upon what invariant you needed each aggregate to enforce.  Trying to nest one aggregate within another suggests that something has gone badly wrong with your aggregate boundaries.

> how to make change of entities and changes of IIS in the same transaction?

Well, you can screw around looking for a way to manage two phase commit, but the usual answer is to send messages to your ports in a separate transaction from the update to the model.  You generally abandon the idea of preventing the model and the remote system from falling out of sync, and instead concentrate on detection and mitigation.

See Udi Dahan's talk on [reliable messaging](https://vimeo.com/111998645).  "Setters" are typically idempotent, so an At Least Once delivery will probably produce a satisfactory result.

> About modeling, how to choose between:

```
tenant.setSite(Site site) { }
tenant.changeSite(Site oldSite, Site newSite) { }
site.AddTenant(Tenant tenant) { }
```

> is there a methodology for that?

The general rule is that "set" should be considered a code smell; put the business logic into the aggregate, and let it make the judgment.  If there's no judgment to be made -- then why is that data member part of the aggregate at all?

Or, put another way, you need to evaluate whether your solution is a database, or a service.  [Borrowing from Udi again](https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/02/service-boundaries-healthcare)...

> Dahan considers that a service has to have both some sort of functionality and some data. If it does not have data, then it is just a function. If all that it does is performing CRUD operations on data, then it is database.

If your solution doesn't get to veto changes, if its responsibility is limited to documenting business decisions that are made somewhere else, then you should be thinking database.